# Google Calendar and XKCD sleep (events repeating in hours)

Tags: google-calendar

So there is this.  [image: xkcd]

This is a bit of a confusing schedule to follow I think, at least for the first little while. It would be handy to be able to put it into, say, a Google Calendar so one could work out where and when you would be.

Unfortunately in Google Calendar you can't say "This event should repeat every X hours" - it only copes with repeating in days, weeks, etc.

So the obvious solution is to do six seperate "sleep" events which each one repeating once a week. Great so far?

The problem with the six separate events is that you might want to have an adjustment in between - so you might occasionally want to get up an hour earlier or go to bed a couple of hour earlier - in such situations you'd like to adjust *only* next sleep time and have everything else adjust by the right amount automatically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So in the absence of other answers - my workaround has been to take advantage of Gcal's ability to import events from an excel file - I set some stuff up in Excel (where it's fairly easy to have events advance by a couple of hours) and then update when I need to - it's not an ideal strategy (It lacks a certain WYSIWYG) but I've no better ideas.